# How to mock a database connection with JUnit?

Tags: java, database, testing, junit, mockito

Simply can't find a concrete example where a db connection is mocked. Preferred with Mockito.

```
public Connection getCon() throws SQLException, Exception {
        Properties login = new Properties();

        TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+2:00");
        TimeZone.setDefault(timeZone);

        Connection conn = null;
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

        return conn;
}
```

Want to test this method...

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to mock static class DriverManager. Here is an answer to exactly your issue:
[Mocking static methods with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito)

Comment: well...still can't figure it out

Comment: @basti throw code, that don't work for you and the exception